# Angularjs Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%string

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and I'm working on a single page-app. I'm getting this error message that doesnt tell me where in my code that's throwing this error and I've went on angularjs' website to look up the error but I dont understand it.

This is the error message I'm getting,

Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%string

Any ideas on what might be throwing this error? Thanks

Edit: The error might have something to do with the way I declare my modules but I still can't figure it out. Here's a sippet of my code ...

```
var user = angular.module('user', ['ui.bootstrap','ngResource']);
user.controller("user", ["$scope", "$resource", "$location", '$state',
  function($scope, $resource, $location, $state) {  }]);

var saveObject = angular.module('saveObject', ['ui.bootstrap','ngResource'])
.factory('savedObject', function($resource) {});

var saveUser = angular.module('saveUser',  ['saveObject']);
saveUser.service('saveUser', 'savedObject', function(savedObject) {});

var route = angular.module('route', ["ui.router", 'ngResource', 'saveUser'])
route.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {});

 route.controller('add_userController', ["$scope", "$resource", '$state', '$timeout', '$rootScope', '$http', 'saveUser',
function($scope, $resource, $state, $timeout, $rootScope, $http, saveUser) {}]);

route.controller('add_familyController', ["$scope", "$resource", '$state', '$timeout', '$rootScope', '$http', '$window', 'saveUser',
function($scope, $resource, $state, $timeout, $rootScope, $http, $window, saveUser) {}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service definition seems to be messed up:

```
var saveUser = angular.module('saveUser',  ['saveObject']);
saveUser.service('saveUser', 'savedObject', function(savedObject) {});
```

should be maybe

```
var saveUser = angular.module('saveUser',  ['saveObject']);
saveUser.service('saveUser', ['savedObject', function(savedObject) {}]);
```